# How to toggle existing class with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, class, dom

I have a navbar with Bootstrap icon inside the anchor tags

Here's my code:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
        <i class="bi bi-house"></i>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
        <i class="bi bi-heart"></i>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
        <i class="bi bi-envelope"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

I want to add `-fill` if it clicked, and remove it when clicking on another navigation. I've tried `classList.toggle`, but is seems just adding new class without appending it.

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
        <i class="bi bi-house-fill"></i>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
        <i class="bi bi-heart"></i>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
        <i class="bi bi-envelope"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the behaviour you're looking for, you'll need to add event listeners to your anchor tags. When an icon is clicked, you should add `-fill` to its class if it's not already there, and for all other icons, you should remove `-fill` if it's present.

For this purpose, you should do as follows:

1. You have to assign a [click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to each navigation item (or alternatively use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) approach)
2. Use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to map through your `navlinks`, get the `<i>` classes, and [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the `-fill` with an empty string.
3. Finally, add the `-fill` to the clicked element if it already doesn't have it.

Here is a working example:

```js
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');

navLinks.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Remove '-fill' from all icons
    navLinks.forEach(otherLink => {
      const icon = otherLink.querySelector('i');
      icon.className = icon.className.replace('-fill', '');
    });

    // Add '-fill' to the clicked icon
    const icon = this.querySelector('i');
    if (!icon.className.includes('-fill')) {
      icon.className = icon.className + '-fill';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">


<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
      <i class="bi bi-house"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
      <i class="bi bi-heart"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
      <i class="bi bi-envelope"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perfect! Actually i forgot my old code, and this is reminds me the structure of my old code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your current approach is that classList.toggle only adds the class if it's not present and removes it if it is. This means it will only switch between the original class and the class with "-fill" appended, not allowing multiple elements to have the "-fill" class simultaneously.

Here's how you can achieve the desired behavior:

**1. Remove existing "-fill" classes:**

Before adding the "-fill" class to the clicked element, you need to remove it from any other element that might have it. This ensures only one element has the active state at a time.

```js
// Select all anchor elements within the navigation
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');

navLinks.forEach(link => {
  // Remove any existing "-fill" class
  link.classList.remove('bi-house-fill', 'bi-heart-fill', 'bi-envelope-fill');
});
```

**2. Add "-fill" class to the clicked element:**

Now, when an anchor element is clicked, you can use classList.toggle to add the "-fill" class specific to the clicked icon.

```js
navLinks.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const icon = link.querySelector('i');
    const iconClass = icon.classList[1]; // Get the second class (e.g., "bi-house")
    icon.classList.toggle(`${iconClass}-fill`);
  });
});
```

**Explanation:**

1. We use `querySelectorAll` to select all anchor elements with the class nav-link.
2. We loop through each link using `forEach`.
3. Inside the loop, we use `classList.remove` to remove any existing "-fill" classes from the icon within the link. This ensures only one element has the active state.
4. We add an event listener to each link for the `click` event.
5. When a link is clicked, we use `querySelector` to get the icon element within the link.
6. We then access the second class name of the icon using `classList[1]`. This assumes the icon class is the second class on the element.
7. Finally, we use `classList.toggle` with a template literal to dynamically construct the class name to be toggled. This ensures the appropriate "-fill" class is added or removed based on the clicked icon.

This approach ensures that only the clicked icon has the "-fill" class, providing the desired visual feedback for the active navigation item.